# Tell mongoose, to add reference in schema instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object declared:

```
var someObject = { someField: someValue }
```

I have schema in mongoose:

```
var achievementSchema = new Schema({    
    _id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },  
    //add reference to declared earlier object
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Achievement', achievementSchema);
```

Now I would like to tell mongoose, to create reference to "someObject" in all new instances.

```
var achievement = new Achievement({
   _id: "someId"     
   reference: //i want mongoose to automatically add reference to object that is already in memory
});
```

And call this reference like this:

```
console.log(achievement.reference);
```

Is it possible in mongoose?

Comment: I am not quite sure I follow. Are you trying to "join" two documents together similar to a RDBMS approach?

Comment: No. I just want to have declared eariel constants, in mongoose schema instance, so I can use them for example: someMongooseSchemaInstance.price

Comment: This is not very clear at all. You want constant values stored in your documents?

Comment: Yes. I want to add constants references, to documents.

Comment: I don't understand why the achievementSchema code is included here. It's not referenced at all.

Comment: What's a "constant reference"? This is so unclear. I'm downvoting and flagging as "unclear what you're asking." You should spend some time clarifying because we're not going to be able to help you unless we understand the problem. If you just want to add subdocuments to a MongoDB document, yes you can do that. If that's not what you're asking, then I don't know how to help you because this question completely confuses me.

Comment: I'm declaring some constats: var constant = "someConstant". I want to tell mongoose, to add references to this constant, when creating schema instances. For example: someInstance.constantReference.

Comment: So you want Mongoose to automatically include this constant when creating new schemas? Or you want new schemas to INHERIT fields from parent schemas?

Comment: New instances of schema.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55208/discussion-between-user3021198-and-mttdbrd).

Comment: Sorry if question was not clear, I'v changed it abit, now it should be more understandable.

Comment: @user3021198 Not really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called [statics](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics). Statics refer to methods, but you might be able to use an object instead.

If you are unable to use an object, you could have a static method return the static object.

Comment: This is not exacly what I asked for, but the answer is very near and helped me alot. Insteed of statics I used methods and it's working. Thank you very much. Spent hours of searching.